Include mean in a multiple ggplot2 graph in vertical axis
I have the following data frame in R called data_f:
> data_f
A tibble: 60 × 4
# Groups:   Year, item [12]
   Year  item  Response            Percentage
   <fct> <chr> <chr>                    <dbl>
 1 2019  A     1-Strongly disagree       20.9
 2 2019  A     2-Disagree                19.9
 3 2019  A     3-so-so                   20.3
 4 2019  A     4-Agree                   19  
 5 2019  A     5-Strongly agree          19.9
 6 2019  B     1-Strongly disagree       20.5
 7 2019  B     2-Disagree                19.9
 8 2019  B     3-so-so                   19.5
 9 2019  B     4-Agree                   21  
10 2019  B     5-Strongly agree          19.2
# ℹ 50 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


And I want this specific plot with ggplot2 package with this code:
data_f%>%
  ggplot(aes(Percentage,Year, fill = Response)) +
  geom_col(position = ggstats::position_likert()) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = ggstats::label_percent_abs()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = "RdYlGn") +
  facet_wrap(~item,dir="v") +
  theme_bw()

But I want to add some percentages. For example I want across the bar in the middle to show me the mean of each Year right in the middle and the x-axis to show 100-50-0-50-100? How can I achieve that?

structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("2019", "2020", "2022", "2023"
), class = "factor"), item = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C"), Response = c("1-Strongly disagree", "2-Disagree", 
"3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree", "1-Strongly disagree", 
"2-Disagree", "3-so-so", "4-Agree", "5-Strongly agree"), Percentage = c(20.9, 
19.9, 20.3, 19, 19.9, 20.5, 19.9, 19.5, 21, 19.2, 20.3, 19.1, 
19.6, 20.3, 20.7, 20.1, 21, 20.1, 19, 19.9, 20.1, 20, 19.6, 18.9, 
21.4, 19.3, 20.7, 20.2, 19.7, 20.2, 20.7, 20, 17.6, 21.3, 20.4, 
19, 20.2, 20.5, 20.4, 19.9, 20.2, 19.4, 19.5, 20.3, 20.6, 19.4, 
19.9, 21.4, 19.8, 19.5, 20.7, 19.7, 18.6, 20.9, 20.1, 18.2, 20.7, 
19.7, 20.3, 21.1)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), groups = structure(list(
    Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L), levels = c("2019", "2020", "2022", "2023"), class = "factor"), 
    item = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
    "B", "C"), .rows = structure(list(1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20, 
        21:25, 26:30, 31:35, 36:40, 41:45, 46:50, 51:55, 56:60), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L), .drop = TRUE))


Also original data can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78297993/how-can-i-convert-a-data-frame-with-only-factors-into-table-with-proportions-in/78298218#78298218

Can you please clarify something? If a survey came back all 1's, what average Percentage would you expect?  -200% (since it's a "-2" normalized score for 100%), or -100% (since it's a perfect negative score), or -40% (the mean of the weighted scores, where we have 100% -2s, averaged with four zeroes)?

Update:
Adding percentages for disagree, neutral, and agree responses based on OP's comments.
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)

data_f %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(res.sgn = sign(as.numeric(substr(Response, -1, 1)) - 3)) %>% 
  summarise(sum.prcnt = sum(Percentage),
            .by = c(Year, item, res.sgn))-> data_f_sum

ggplot(data = data_f, 
       aes(Percentage, Year, fill = Response)) +
  geom_col(position = position_likert()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.25),
                     labels = ggstats::label_percent_abs()) +
  geom_label(data = data_f_sum,
            aes(label = sprintf("%.1f", sum.prcnt), y = Year, x = res.sgn * 0.5),
            alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = "RdYlGn") +
  facet_wrap(~item, dir="v") +
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-04-10 with reprex v2.0.2


Here's another method using geom_errorbar:
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)

data_f %>% 
  group_by(Year, item) %>% 
  mutate(mean.resp = 
           sum((as.numeric(substr(Response, -1, 1)) - 3) * Percentage/100)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Percentage,Year, fill = Response)) +
  geom_col(position = position_likert()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.25),
                     labels = label_percent_abs()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(y = Year, xmax = mean.resp, xmin = mean.resp), 
                inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(mean.resp, 1), y = Year, x = mean.resp), 
            hjust = -0.5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = "RdYlGn") +
  facet_wrap(~item, dir="v") +
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-04-10 with reprex v2.0.2

Awesome.But I want only the value to be displayed not the | bar.Otherwise is what I needed.Thank you very much

@HomerJaySimpson in that case just remove geom_errorbar line and get rid of hjust in geom_text.

If we are trying to get the weighted mean of the adjusted scores, I think you want the sum of the post-weighted elements (where you have the score x pct), not the mean. For example, if our survey responses are all 1s, normalized to all scores of -2, yours would say the average is -0.4, instead of -2 which is what I would expect. Or maybe we take your approach and multiply by 2.5, so that 100% 1's = -1 and 100% 5s = +1.   Also, what does it mean that the bars extend from around -100% to around +100%? That makes it look like each survey has about 200%.

@JonSpring both of your points are valid. I should've definitely used sum instead of mean. About the 100 to 100, honestly I am not sure why OP needs that or what does that suppose to mean, I was just following their request saying: "... and the x-axis to show 100-50-0-50-100...". I answered solely to show the use of geom_errorbar which I think is better than using geom_linerange in this case. Cheers.

@M-- Actually i want to display 3 percentages (3 values) on each year. The middle value must be the percentage of the 3rd category.NOT THE MEAN. I misunderstood. Jon Spring is correct. The other value that i want to appear in the left side on each year to be the mean or the 2 lower Likert scale categories 5th and 4th in the right side the mean of the two highest categories 1st and 2nd. Like the plot here

@HomerJaySimpson in that case, see my updates.

Assuming we can average the Likert scale responses (some would advise this doesn't make sense, since those responses may have non-linear interpretations), you could do something like:
data_f %>%
  ggplot(aes(Percentage,Year)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Response), position = ggstats::position_likert()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Percentage, accuracy = 0.1)),
                data = data_f %>%
    summarize(Percentage = sum((parse_number(Response)-3) * Percentage / 100))) +

  # original response, just showing vertical line "across the bar"
  # geom_linerange(aes(ymin = as.numeric(Year) - 0.4, 
  #                    ymax = as.numeric(Year) + 0.4),
  #                      data = data_f %>%
  #              summarize(Percentage = sum((parse_number(Response)-3) * Percentage / 100))) +
  ...



Thank you but I think i didn’t set my question correctly.I want to show me the number not the bar
